# Select a record based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have 3 tables. Table 1 gets updated every time I upload a file. Table 2 is an archival table that stores records in all files uploaded. Table 3 stores data of table 2 after some validations.

1st File upload:

Table 1:

```
RefNo   |   Code   |  ID 
--------+----------+-----
1234         30        1     
5678         40        2
```

Table 2:

```
RefNo   |   Code   |  ID
--------+----------+------
1234         30        1
5678         40        2
```

2nd File upload

Table 1:

```
RefNo   |   Code   |  ID 
--------+----------+-----
1234         50        3     
5678         60        4
```

Table 2:

```
RefNo   |   Code   |  ID
--------+----------+------
1234         30        1
5678         40        2
1234         50        3     
5678         60        4
```

3rd File upload (UPDATE code=100 for refno = 1234)

Table 1:

```
RefNo   |   Code   |  ID 
--------+----------+------
1234         100        5
```

Table 2:

```
RefNo   |   Code   |  ID
--------+----------+------
1234         30        1
5678         40        2
1234         50        3     
5678         60        4
1234         100       5
```

Now, there are 3 records for 1234 in table 2. I want to update code to 100 in table 3 only if last uploaded code is 0. How can I select the last uploaded record?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table2 a 
JOIN table 1 b ON a.refno = b.refno 
WHERE a.id = (SELECT ???)
```

I don't know how to pick ID = 3 (last uploaded one) and not multiple IDs.

Comment: what is the structure of table3 like

Comment: Where's the "last uploaded code"?

Comment: last uploaded code is 50 in this case

Comment: ```
table 3
RefNo | Code | Message | ID
```

Comment: why would 50 be last uploaded code and not 100

Comment: @Kevin i meant 100 is the latest uploaded code and 50 is what i need to check for.

Answer (score 0):

if the ids are type int, you can use this to get the last record for all refno's in table1 that exist in table2. Then you can filter those as needed:

```
select  t2.*
from    table2 t2
join    (           
            select  t2.RefNo,
                    MAX(t2.ID) lastId
            from    table2 t2
            JOIN    table1 t1 ON t2.RefNo = t1.RefNo 
            WHERE   t2.Id < t1.Id
            GROUP BY t2.RefNo
        ) ti        on t2.Id = ti.lastId
```